# Move Apple Notes from Mac to iCloud

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, icloud, notes.app

I have all my notes on my Mac, and I want to move them to iCloud so I can use them on a different laptop. Using the image below as an example, how do I move all notes from "On My Mac" to "iCloud" so that they are stored on iCloud?

[image]

Comment: there are 11 answers to that question and none were selected as being correct.  Without a selected answer op would maybe have to try them all.

Comment: Doesn’t that mean we put a bounty on the old question to get a good answer? Let me see if the old question is irredeemable. If someone has an answer they know works for Mojave or Catalina - let’s edit that in this question and get an answer up pronto.

Comment: @bmike I've solved this problem. None of the answers in that other question helped me as they are mostly for the iPhone. Can you reopen this question so that I can post an answer that works?

Comment: Yes please. You can flag as other once you have a solid comment like that. Any mod can assist glad to help. We still may [merge to another question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/401753/move-apple-notes-from-mac-to-icloud) , but let’s get an answer up to see what you learned

Comment: @BlackPanther what was the solve?

Comment: @bmike just found time to post an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you turn on iCloud after already creating notes in the Apple Notes app, those notes will be local to the device, and are not automatically added to iCloud.

To add local notes to iCloud manually you can select an item, and then move it to a new list by dragging the "Notes" folder under the "On My Mac" list to the iCloud list.

[On macOS you may have a move all](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/215437/5472) option as well.

Answer (score 1):

in your image you have 126 Notes on icloud and 14 on your computer. To add notes to icloud just click the icloud link on the left and click on the 'add a note' icon to add new note.

You should backup you notes before doing this. There is an app called [Note2Txt.app](http://toolsandtoys.net/note2txt-export-apple-notes/) that will extract all your notes to individual text files. You can specify the folder to store the notes in and it runs quickly. You can store the folder with your notes in them anywhere you want.

Comment: I don't want to add a new note to iCloud. I want to add an existing note. How do I do this?

Comment: oh i misunderstood. you could look at existing note and copy it, then create a new icloud note and paste it in.

Comment: No worries. The screenshot I used is an example, not the real thing. I have around 1000 notes so copy paste is not feasible. Does the Note2Txt.app preserve images and links in a note?

Comment: that i don't know.